# Intermittent Problems with Galleria

Tags: javascript, web, galleria

My Galleria is temperamental, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt. I was going to put galleria into my website and I had it up and running but for some strange reason it is very temperamental and it only works if you quickly go the gallery on tab 2 before the page finishes loading! Ive tried this on Safari and Firefox and get same story (My site doesnt seem to run on IE, the layout is all wrong).

My website is "http://www.milltownyourlocalchurch.com/", in case you need to look at the html which might help solve this problem. If u load the page and quickly go to tab 2 before the page loads (which is were the gallery is, at the bottom), then it will show ok. BUT, if u let the page completely finish loading then go to the gallery it will not have displayed. This leads me to believe there is something in the page load that knocks of the galleria.

Has anyone else had this problem or know how to fix it??

Galleria is declared in the "head" tag

```
<script src="js/galleria.js"></script>
<script>Galleria.loadTheme('classic/galleria.classic.js');</script>
```

And code is added in the body section too

```
<script>$('.galleria').galleria();</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting two JS errors on that page. I'd try to fix those first and then see whether the gallery works. FYI: `$('#features').cycle()` causes the first problem, since you don't seem to include the necessary plugin.

Comment: Never mind, i know how to do this in Firefox now, under tools->Error Console. Although in brings up a list of about 20 errors, 3 of them fatal errors. Thats not good. Il have to investigate them, but il focus on the galleria fatal errors first.

Comment: Ok, problem solved with the help of polarblau. I checked Javascript errors using error console and figured out that you have to specify the WIDTH as well as the height of Galleria in order for this to work. The problem is now fixed.